# liferay Dxp : How to redirect from a portel in one page to another page , which contains different portlet , when clicked on a hyperlink

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

liferay 7.1: I have two pages p1 and p2, on p1 I have a portlet A in which some blog title are listed, upon clicking on this, I want to redirect to page2 which contains a portlet, which will show details of blog.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. This is a very broad question, please be more specific: What have you tried so far, what did you observe? Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/web/configuration/show-account">redirect</a>"
```

redirect to the page where your portlet is being placed.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the href to the name of the second page.

If you are using aui:

```
<aui:a href="yourSecondPageName">
```

If not:

```
<a href="yourSecondPageName">
```